# One word for act of anchoring an event/seminar

Tags: vocabulary

I feel it's pronounced "camp-our-ing"(not correct)

I tried searching a lot but couldn't find the exact word.
Could someone please help me

Comment: By "anchoring", you don't mean attaching a big heavy boat anchor, right? Then what do you mean?

Comment: Yup. Right. I mean hosting an event like a TV show

Comment: How about MC, as in Master of Ceremonies

Comment: Or Could you just suggest another word for a person hosts an event like a prize distribution ceremony?

Comment: What's the matter with _host_? That's the norm, or M.C, for a variety show where every act needs an introduction. As for "camp-our-ing", the only thing I can think of is _empowering_, which seems wrong, even given the fragmentary context we have.

Comment: Is the word you're looking for *championing*? As in, "She really championed the charity seminar last weekend."

Comment: This question involves a very peculiar use of the word *anchoring* http://www.gradywhite.com/docklines/files/20091117/index_files/Anchoring.jpg

Comment: @JohnLawler Really, compère, compèring, no ? I daren't answer in case this question turns out to be too basic.

Comment: @Frank: In American English I have never heard anyone use the word _compère_; for one thing, it would be heard as _compare_, and for another, it's not a French word that's been borrowed into American English and therefore would not be on the menu of available meanings. We still haven't got any idea what word OP is searching for.

Comment: @JohnLawler Maybe it's a British thing. I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @JohnLawler The pronunciation is different. *Compere* is stressed on the first syllable, *compare* on the second. I have no idea whether French does that.

Comment: @Tristan: I don't move in circles where I'd be likely to encounter or use this sort of word very often, but it would seem natural to me that those who *do* would easily make the tiny shift from ***act as anchorman*** to plain ***anchor*** as the relevant verb.

Comment: FumbleFingers, it doesn't seem natural to me. I've only heard the word *anchor* used in nautical contexts. It does not seem logical to use it in the question here. It seems out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is ***compering***. It doesn't appear to have made it into American English.

> **compere** *British* /ˈkɒmpɛː/
>
> *noun*
>   A person who introduces the performers or contestants in a variety show.
>
> *verb*
>   Act as a compère for (a variety show):
>   *Mark Wilson compered the whole proceedings*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/compere?q=compere)

The pronunciation is very similar to *compare* but the stress is on the first syllable (including in *compering*).

Comment: snap ! (and then some)

Answer (score 0):

Is the word you are looking for *compèring*

It sounds exactly like the common word *comparing*.

Here's a web based definition of the word.
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compering

Comment: The audience had better not be American English speakers. Plus, if you want to avoid confusion with _compare_, be sure to stress the first syllable in speech, and be sure to include the accent grave in writing.

Comment: What @John said. Brits also make the same distinction in pronunciation (though I personally wouldn't care whether the accent was present in the written form or not).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree. _compère_ doesn't sound like _compare_, but _compèring_ sounds just the same as _comparing_ to me. I wouldn't use the accent in writing either, to be honest I wouldn't use the word in writing.

Comment: @ Frank: Your profile doesn't specify location, but I think I can safely say I speak for most if not all Brits in agreeing with John (who probably speaks for *all* Anglophones far more than I can even claim to speak for the people I converse with regularly). That's to say *compering* always stresses the first syllable, whereas *comparing* stresses the second.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My present location wouldn't help you determine much anyway but my accent is a blend of English (Richmond), South African, Scottish and Australian (without the question per sentence part). I would never claim it was RP. I'm told often I pronounce the word 'not' as 'note' but for the life of me I can't hear it. I should perhaps refrain from commenting on matters of pronunciation.

Comment: @ Frank: I don't think your "multifarious" background in terms of contributions to your accent should be any reason for not contributing to such questions. And it certainly sounds to me as if it would be a real advantage sometimes for others to be able to discover that information from your profile. I know my South African dentist sometimes uses what I think of as non-standard intonation - but he seems very well-educated, so I assume it's all to do with his background (his actual *accent* isn't actually very noticeable).

Comment: @JohnLawler Is that really not a US term? All this time I had assumed it was. I have in my mind _aaaaaaand a big welcome for your compère of the Tonight Show, Heeeeeeere's Johnny!_ introducing Johnny Carson.

Comment: I guarantee that Johnny Carson was never introduced using the word _compère_. I doubt that Ed McMahon could have pronounced it.

Comment: I remember Eric Idle using it to describe himself in Monty Python as he introduced Harry Fink.